# SQL Query for multiple tables/records

Tags: sql

I have to create a query that compiles a bunch of data for each player (user) from multiple tables.  For instance, I have two tables: **`tblMembers`** and **`Off_Ice_Testing`**.

There are multiple off_ice_testing for each tblMembers (or none). How do I select one off_ice_testing that has the latest date?

I tried:

```
   SELECT m.LastName, 
          m.FirstName, 
          office.Date AS [off ice date]
   FROM tblMembers AS m 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date, UserID
              FROM Off_Ice_Testing) AS office ON m.UserID = office.UserID
   WHERE m.LastName LIKE '%player%'
```

But that gets back a record for each **`Off_ice_Testing`**. If I do **Top(1)** in the derived table, that won't work. I feel like I should know this, but I'm stuck. And for future reference, what would you call this type of query?

Comment: Which SQL are you using (Oracle or MSSQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.LastName, m.FirstName, o.[Date] AS [off ice date]
FROM tblMembers AS m
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT UserID, MAX([Date]) as [Date] FROM Off_Ice_Testing
  GROUP BY UserID
)o ON (o.UserID = m.UserID)
WHERE     (m.LastName LIKE '%player%')
```

Comment: Ahhh, of course, a MAX(Date). However, I realized, you also needed a Group By UserID for the derived table (at least for MSSQL). Thanks!

Comment: Oops.. Yeah, I forgot it :) Fixing